# Android preferences show value and unit

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to show a preference with the unit (while still only taking the value)

For example:

Having the preference Distance which is a EditTextPreference
and the preference Distance Unit which is a ListPreference

So when they are displayed it shows:

```
Distance
value + unit

Distance Unit
unit
```

Example:

```
Distance
5 km
Distance Unit
km
```

then change distance unit:

```
Distance
5 mi
Distance Unit
mi
```

However, all I really care about is the 5, but i still want to show the unit beside it. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example code? How do you output the result?

Comment: Right know my class extends PreferenceActivity and use preference.setSummary(value);

Comment: I was talking about how you are outputing the result. If you are outputing it as a string, you just need to concatenate two strings.

If your problem is about storing the preference, shared preferences work with key-value pairs. You just need to create a new key-value pair in which you store the unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Just implement a custom onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) for your Distance and your Unit.

Find your preference with the Distance-key and use setSummary(String summary) to append the unit to the distance.

Here some fancy code:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
   if (key.equals("distance") | key.equals("unit")) {
      findPreference("distance").setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("distance", "0") + sharedPreferences.getString("unit", "km"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to only save the value though, rather than the value + the unit?

Comment: setSummary() won't save anything. It will only display something.
And if you don't save the unit, how do you want to determine which unit to append?

Comment: I do save the unit, I didn't realize setSummary() doesn't save the value, but only displays it. Thank you